# This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources after ssl from sslforfree

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, unauthorized

I am getting error that

> This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources

after doing SSL from SSL for free

how to solve please help

Comment: Please show your code, including the URL to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your page has link href tag connected to a website which doesn't have SSL.

If you want to check these href links:-
On your computer, open Chrome.
Go to your website.
At the top right, click More (vertical triple dots).
Click More tools and then Developer tools.
In the right sidebar, at the top, click Console.

Here you'll see which scripts are trying to load from unauthenticated sources.

Comment: Can also right-click > Inspect. In my case the issue was a png image (which I don't think of as a "script" but chrome does). My page used https, png was http.